# missing Sync button in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, onedrive-for-business

I have checked the list setting-Advanced setting-offline availability and in 
Site setting- Search and offline availability I have enabled the Sync button but it does not show up in the pages. What should I do?

Comment: is it missing or disbale?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE missing.

Comment: is issue with one customer or all, did you try to check other browser? tryt o clear browser cache...also close browser and open it

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE have tried with different browsers and have deleted history and cache

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this? I have the same issue. Missing "sync" button on the OneDrive for Business 2013 site so I cannot sync the filed to my pc.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's only applied to Document libraries and To add synchronization to all document libraries as shown below

[image]

- Try to run the following command using SharePoint Management Shell.

> ```
> Get-SPSite -limit all | get-SPWeb -limit all | Foreach { $_.Title = $_.Title; $_.ExcludeFromOfflineClient=0; $_.Update() }
> ```

[PowerShell Cmdlet Ref](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169080.aspx)